# Change fragment onAdclose. Interstitial ad

Tags: android, asynchronous, fragment

## I would like to change the fragment after ad is closed.

But It throws me an IllegalStateException

*Fragment1 :*

```
...
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this.getContext());
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        masterActivity.showGame(); // <---- here comes the error
    }
});
requestNewInterstitial();

// Action Listener on Button show game
Button btnShowGame = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnShowGame);
btnShowGame.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            masterActivity.showGame();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

*MasterActivity :*

```
...
public void showGame() {
    FragmentGameBoard fragment = new FragmentGameBoard();
    fragment.setMasterActivity(this);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Which result in :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

From this post it seems like the error is normal :
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

--> **"Avoid performing transactions inside asynchronous callback methods."**

But how to achieve what I want to do ?

It obviously has something to do with ads and asynchronous logic.

I don't want the user to have to click the button a second time to switch fragment.

## Actual

`fragment1 -(clickButton)-> interstitialAd -(closeAd)-> fragment1 -(clickButton)-> fragment2`

## Expected

`fragment1 -(clickButton)-> interstitialAd -(closeAd)-> fragment2`

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the same problem, and managed to solve it as follows

Inside showGame() change the follow line

Instead of:

`transaction.commit();`

use:

`transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();`